# Windows file share - change permissions on a specific folder name that appears in multiple subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, powershell, permissions, windows-server-2008, file-sharing

We have a Windows Server 2008 shared folder, with the following structure:

```
Customer info
    Customer name (many customers folders)
        Project name (many more projects folders)
            01 Quotes & Orders
            02 Project Management
            03 Engineering
            04 Misc
```

I need to change the permission on the `01 Quotes & Orders` folder, inside every `\{customer info}\{customer name}\{project name}\` path.

I'm thinking a script that would give me the full path of every 01 Quotes & Orders folder, then use that as an input to change the permissions.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Always be sure to start by showing what you have tried so far. For example, the progress you've made on a script like you suggest, and showing where you are unable to figure out how to go further.

Comment: Thanks. It was my first post. I'll keep it in mind next time. @ProgrammerDan.

Comment: Great, that was my hope! And of course, welcome to StackOverflow :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you could do something like this

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\CustomerInfo' -Filter '01 Quotes & Orders' -Recurse
```

to get a list of all `01 Quotes & Orders` objects. Pipe the output of the above command into a [`ForEach-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) loop and use [`Get-Acl`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx)/[`Set-Acl`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx) to modify the folders' permissions.